# Merge Style.Triggers with property Template in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to set a style for my DataGrid, but I do not know where is the problem
the backgroud property does not work with its value in the presence of the Template property.

my code:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SeaGreen"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Border Name="DataGridCellBorder">
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Background="Transparent" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                            Height="auto" Width="auto" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **explicitly set TextBlock background to Transparent**, so it won't pick value from `DataGridCell`. You should bind with background of DataGridCell using `RelativeSource` like this:

```
<TextBlock Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}}"
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
           Height="auto" Width="auto" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```